# Keycloak 2fa via SMS using external REST Api

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have been trying to implement 2fa using OTP. Till now i am successful doing it via browser flow using keycloak interface to login. Keycloak provides an API to give the access token after passing username, password & client-secret,

i.e. http://localhost:8080/realms/SpringBootKeycloak/protocol/openid-connect/token

Is there any any external api available to trigger my custom flow of sending OTP and verifying it, if not how can i implement this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77883850/1544452 which has an answer

Answer (score -1):

Keycloak doesn't provide any API to verify the OTP.

> Keycloak provides an API to give the access token after passing username,
> password & client-secret

Most likely you're talking here about [Resource owner password credentials grant (Direct Access Grant)](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_oidc-auth-flows-direct).

The latest [OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://oauth.net/2/oauth-best-practice/) spec actually **recommends against using the Password grant entirely**, and it is being removed in the OAuth 2.1 update. ([source](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/password-grant/)).

Unless you have more specific requirements rather than just login and OTP, I'd recommend you to use a regular [authorization code flow](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_oidc-auth-flows-authorization) instead as a default way of authorization. Using this flow you'd be redirected to Keycloak login page and configure OTP to be displayed there without using Keycloak APIs.