# Keycloak direct grant by password or otp

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, totp

How to get access token via API POST https://{mydomain}/realms/Resource/protocol/openid-connect/token
by password or opt (FE will provide appropriate the param depend on user chose).

I already config the direct grant flow like below on keycloak version 23.0.4

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSUdC.png

Thank you!

More detail, api returns 401 when I add OTP step and set it to Alternative. If I disable OTP, it returns 200
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu7xy.png)

Comment: I implemented the same flow for Browser authen flow and it worked. But Direct grant is not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Keycloak direct grant flow supports `otp` as a param. Which means that you have to send `username`, `password`, `grant_type=password` and `otp` with the number that was generated. Something like this:

```
curl -d "client_id=yourclient" \
    -d "client_secret=yourclientsecret" \
    -d "username=theUsername" \
    --data-urlencode  "password=thePassword" \
    -d "scope=openid" \
    -d "otp=113454" \
    -d "grant_type=password" \
    https://{mydomain}/realms/Resource/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Comment: where in the documentation or code did you figure out the `otp` parameter for the kc oidc token endpoint ?

Comment: @Zailux I read the Keycloak code. You can find tests where totp/otp are sent: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/cecce40aa5d957f765487b790f4324ec742be60c/testsuite/integration-arquillian/tests/base/src/test/java/org/keycloak/testsuite/oauth/ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrantTest.java#L316 & https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/cecce40aa5d957f765487b790f4324ec742be60c/testsuite/integration-arquillian/tests/base/src/main/java/org/keycloak/testsuite/util/OAuthClient.java#L603-L624